# using flex tree, how can I know a drag'n'drop operation have been performed?

Tags: apache-flex, events, drag-and-drop, tree

I have a flex tree (well, an extension of flex tree) in which I want to know which item is currently selected. For that, i've used the classical `change="{changeHandler}"` event.

But, for applicative reasons, I want that when a drag'n'drop operation is performed, this change handler either don't get invoked, or don't perform any change (I can write a `if(!dragNDropPerformed) {...}`).

According to Flash builder debugger, that `change` event is sent after the mouse button has been released, as a consequence the drag'n'drop operation has been ended. So, in such a context, how can I know a drag'n'drop operation has just been performed and my click should not be considered as a "valid" one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree has a "dragComplete" and "dragDrop" event that you can listen for.

Examples: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_7.html#247940